# AWS OpenSearch give user read only access dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, kibana, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I am using aws OpenSearch to view real-time data analysis.

I am using Following roles to give my user read-only access to dashboard as mentioned [here](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security-plugin/access-control/users-roles/#set-up-a-read-only-user-in-opensearch-dashboards)

- kibana_user
- kibana_read_only
- read_only_index

But still the user can edit dashboard because of some permissions in "kibana_user" role. so i tried to make a duplicate role using OpenSearch build-in functionality and removed manage and delete permission from duplicated role and assign this role to my user. But this time the user is unable to view dashboard and dashboards list **even if I don't removes manage and delete permission**, I am getting the following error in browser

**no permissions for [indices:data/read/search] and User [name=test-user-1, backend_roles=[], requestedTenant=]: security_exception**

I tried giving "indices:data/read/search" this permission to role and many more but it didn't work. any solutions

Answer (score 1):

I used:

```
kibana_all_read
read
```

That seems to work, they can put the dashboard in edit mode, but can't save it.

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach for a Read-Only Dashboard user is as follows:

1. Create a custom role for this type of user: `my-readonly-role`.
2. Add `cluster_composite_ops_ro` cluster permission.
3. Add any desired index patterns to restrict access: `logs.*`.
4. Add index privileges for read access: `read`, `indices:admin/resolve/index`.
5. Add Tenant patterns: `My-Tenant`
6. Add Tenant permissions: `read`, `write`
7. Map the following roles to desired users: `my-readonly-role` and `opensearch_dashboards_read_only`

**Note:** This was tested against OpenSearch version 1.1.

[Create a Role (API)](https://opensearch.org/docs/1.1/security-plugin/access-control/api#create-role)

Here is the API block that represents the above steps:

```json
{
    "cluster_permissions": ["cluster_composite_ops_ro"],
    "index_permissions": [
        {
            "index_patterns": ["logs.*"],
            "dls": "",
            "fls": [],
            "masked_fields": [],
            "allowed_actions": ["read", "indices:admin/resolve/index"]
        }
    ],
    "tenant_permissions": [
        {
            "tenant_patterns": ["My-Tenant"],
            "allowed_actions": ["read", "write"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This works for aws public domain opensearch but it fails in for opensearch domain created in a vpc

Comment: We have this deployed in a private VPC and it works just fine. Your configured method of authentication will need to be factored in, but that is beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: I have logged to the Opensearch dashboard as admin. I am not able to see the "opensearch_dashboards_read_only" in the roles list. May I know how can I find this role to map to my created internal user?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing of the above worked for me but this did. [image]

I don't even know why and how.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, and this seemed to work for me.

**Step 1:** Create a new custom role, in this example we'll name it "my-readonly-role".

- As stated in other posts and in the OpenSearch documentation, it must have the cluster permission "cluster_composite_ops_ro".
- What does not seem to be well documented, is that the index permissions for the indices used by the dashboards, must include the allowed actions "read" and "indices:data/read/search*".
- What also does not seem to be well documented, is that you must declare index permissions for indices matching both ".kibana*" and ".opensearch_dashboards*" and its allowed actions must include "read".

Here is an example API payload that implements the above steps:

```
{
  "cluster_permissions": [
    "cluster_composite_ops_ro"
  ],
  "index_permissions": [
    {
      "index_patterns": ["some_pattern*"],
      "dls": "",
      "fls": [],
      "masked_fields": [],
      "allowed_actions": ["read", "indices:data/read/search*"]
    },
    {
      "index_patterns": [".kibana*", ".opensearch_dashboards*"],
      "dls": "",
      "fls": [],
      "masked_fields": [],
      "allowed_actions": ["read"]
    }
  ],
  "tenant_permissions": [
    {
      "tenant_patterns": ["*"],
      "allowed_actions": ["read"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Step 2:** Assign your backend_roles and/or users to both your new custom role "my-readonly-role" as well as the out of the box role "opensearch_dashboards_read_only".

There may be better ways to do this, and the end user experience is not great to be honest, meaning read only users can still click edit dashboard and proceed to change things, but will get an error when they try to save.  But at least this keeps them from being able to save dashboard changes, and also prevents/restricts them from navigating to "non-dashboard" parts of the web UI (security, stack management, etc.).